# variable outside of function is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/luketheterrible/BMedV/

I am writing a quiz where the user has to select from two options by clicking on the div on the left or the div on the right.

```
$('#answers').on('click', 'div', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var input = "";

    function userAnswer(event) {
        var target = $(event.target);
        if(target.is('#answerLeft')) {
            alert("you clicked left");
            input = "left";
            return input;
        } else {
            alert("you clicked right");
            input = "right";
            return input;
        }
        return input;
    }

    alert(input);
    });
});
```

For some reason, the variable "input" is winding up undefined.  Despite lots of searching, I cannot seem to find an answer as to the best way to define input as being whichever div the user clicked.

Comment: You define your function `userAnswer`, but you never call it.

Comment: `"" !== undefined`

Comment: Why is there a nested function in the first place?

Comment: To hopefully answer all the questions, I have been working with jQuery for only 2 or 3 weeks now.

Thank you for answering anyway!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define your function `userAnswer`, but you never call it.

```
userAnswer(event); // execute the function
alert(input);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/BMedV/1/

---

Better yet, remove the function entirely:

```
$('#answers').on('click', 'div', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var input = "";
    //which answer did the user pick
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('#answerLeft')) {
        input = "left";
    } else {
        input = "right";
    }
    alert(input);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/prPmJ/

Comment: Yep.  That works great!  Thanks Blazemonger!!

Answer (score 1):

You are never calling your method...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#answers').on('click', 'div', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var input = userAnswer(event); // Need to call this method...

    //which answer did the user pick
        function userAnswer(event) {
            var target = $(event.target);
            if(target.is('#answerLeft')) {
                alert("you clicked left");
                input = "left";
                return input;
            } else {
                alert("you clicked right");
                input = "right";
                return input;
            }
            return input;
        }

        alert(input);
    });
});
```

Comment: `var input = userAnswer(event);`

Answer (score 1):

No need to define a function http://jsfiddle.net/BMedV/5/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#answers').on('click', 'div', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var input = "";

    //which answer did the user pick
        //function userAnswer(event) {
            var target = $(event.target);
            if(target.is('#answerLeft')) {
                alert("you clicked left");
                input = "left";
                //return input;
            } else {
                alert("you clicked right");
                input = "right";
                //return input;
            }
            //return input;
        //}

        //alert(input);
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 but you should probably get rid of those `return` statements.

Comment: user will not get alert

Comment: I don't think this deserves a -1 since it's the best solution. Just needed to be cleaned up.

Comment: Right.  The returns and the alerts were just debugging. I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working, so I was trying to pin down where the problem was.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use data attributes to get the answer text directly.

HTML

```
<div id="answerLeft" data-answer="left"></div>
<div id="answerRight" data-answer="right"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#answers').on('click', 'div', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 

        var input = $(this).data("answer");
        alert(input);
    });
});
```

I updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMedV/3/) to show this:

Comment: Thanks, Martin!  That is a lot cleaner than what I had.

Answer (score 0):

the answer has been given, you never call the function so input is never given a value. however, a tip for future debugging: when a variable ends up having no value like that, it usually means it was never given one, its gets over written, or you have a scope issue.

many times its scope, look at where the variable is defined and where you're setting / calling it.

if you're sure its not a scope issue, its most likely one of the other 2. the best way to find out which is to place debug or (shudder!) alerts, throughout the code and follow the messages. so every few lines pop in a message and print out the variable. you'll be able to see if it ever gets a value, and it that value gets lost.

make sure you put messages in all functions too, this way if at the end you dont see any of the messages from one or more functions you know those functions where never called on, thats why the messages didn't show.

in this case massages placed in your function would not show up and it would be quickly obvious the function was never called.

HTH
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, that is exactly why I had all of those alerts in there. I was using the dev tools in chrome to pause at the end of the function, but input was always undefined so I just started throwing the alerts around like a crazy person.